Where to create symlinks to sysfs iio files
I wrote a driver that exposes I2C registers via an IIO device, this device operates in direct mode (read/write directly to files in sysfs), the files are correctly created in sysfs and work fine.
I would like to expose these files in a user-friendly way, I was thinking of creating symlinks to the sysfs files with a udev rule so that instead of having to read /sys/bus/i2c/devices/5-0042/iio\:device1/in_pressure_raw the user can read from a file like /run/the_tank/pressure.
What's the best place for such files? /dev? /run?

If it's a device file that can be used as block or character device, put it in /dev. However, it sounds like it's not like that, but a complex property hierarchy.
I'd say it's in the right place: /sys sysfs, exactly where I, as a user, would expect it to be. /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device*/ is where I'd look, myself!
/run is definitely not the place – that's for sockets, runtime files etc, not hardware.
If you really want to make symlinks using udev, /sys/devices/sensor_actors/ maybe? But anything outside of /sys/bus/iio will not make userland libiio users very happy.
